# Showing modals on $(document).ready(function () {

Tags: php, html, json, ajax, sqlsrv

I have this fiddle from [How enable button when no results found datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221203/how-enable-button-when-no-results-found-datatables). My problem is when I'm trying to associate it with showing modals, it wont work.

My **New** button is disabled on default, and can only be enabled when there's no result in dataTable.

My dataTable works perfectly fine, it's the modal that's not showing whenever I click ***New** when tried to search random text in dataTable to display no results.

```
<a href="#addnew" id="addnew" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-flat" disabled="true"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New</a>
```

Is it possible for this script to work without `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('#example1').dataTable( {
    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
        if ($(".dataTables_empty")[0]) {
            $('#addnew').prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $('#addnew').prop("disabled", true);
        }
    }
  } );
});
```

I'm currently using this as my global dataTable script.

```
$(function () {
    $('#example1').DataTable({
      responsive: true
    })
```

This is my addnew.

```
$(function(){

$("body").on('click', '.addnew', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#addnew').modal('show');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    getRow(id);
  });
});
```